# Filter inside angular controller not behaving as expected

Tags: angularjs, json

I am using a filter inside angular controller in the following way, as per my requirement only `$scope.codeSubFiltered` should be filtered and not `$scope.codeSub`

After filtering the size/length of both `$scope.codeSub` and `$scope.codeSubFiltered` are getting reduced and data is filtered in both.

Please find the code below:

```
$http.get("http://hackerearth.0x10.info/api/ctz_coders?type=json&query=list_submissions&page=1")
              .then(function(response) {
                  $scope.codeSub = response.data;       
                });  

        $scope.codeSubFiltered=$scope.codeSub;
         $scope.$watch('search', function(val)
            {        
                $scope.codeSubFiltered.websites= $filter('filter')($scope.codeSubFiltered.websites, {language: val});

                alert(Object.keys($scope.codeSubFiltered.websites).length);
                alert(Object.keys($scope.codeSub.websites).length);

            }
```

Comment: Do not include pictures with code or even worse, link to pictures. Add the code in the question

Comment: Did the below answer work for you? If not what error are you facing now?

Answer (score 1):

The reason both vars are changed is that they both refer to the same object.

Instead of: `$scope.codeSubFiltered = $scope.codeSub;`

Do: 
`$scope.codeSubFiltered = angular.copy($scope.codeSub);`

Comment: Thanks @timenomad.
It was helpful.